# Read configuration settings from XML file for Gtk3 application

Tags: python, xml, gtk3

I am trying to develop a desktop application using Gtk3 and Python. It's basically a Twitter client. I had intended to store the authentication settings (access token and access token secret) in an XML file. Now I wish to read them on the launch of the application.

The problem I have is where to place the code for reading the XML file.

The authentication requires the following steps:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cons_key,cons_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

I can't place the read code in the constructor of the main window, as when the window opens, the methods for getting the tweets is called. I have placed my code on [github](https://github.com/gauravsood91/PyGTweet).

The XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<credentials>
 <access_token>
  76611638-TSnLa31lRXEp3qBNpxKmi2gyiW0jCLpOKeEsK5i6A
 </access_token>
 <access_token_secret>
  wgC9xwGpCMOQQtDazOZF7wtvCA5MrtcaLT6gLv1vdE
 </access_token_secret>
</credentials>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

Try to read the xml at the start of your program (with `lxm`).
Initialize your `api` with the data read from the xml.

in `MainWindow.__init__()`:

Declare/create `self.myapi=api`

Use `self.myapi` in your class methods (`MainWindow`'s methods) and `api` in your functions.

**OLD**:

Why don't you try to move:

```
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(cons_key,cons_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api=tweepy.API(auth)
```

to:

```
#Class of the main window
class MainWindow():
    #Main Window constructor
    def __init__(self):
        message=['','','','','','','','','','']
        users=['','','','','','','','','','']
        image_url=['','','','','','','','','','']

        #read xml here (with lxml)
        #get credentials
        #get auth

        statuses=api.home_timeline()
        loader=GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader()
```

If this doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: i can't push the reading of the file there, as my methods for making tweets and stream are outside the class, and they use the api object. i tried initializing an api object before the class with the token values as null just to avoid error, and reinitialized an api object with the real values read from file, but because of that, the tokens expired.

Comment: it would not work, as if there is no access tokens present, there would be error. anyways, i managed to form functions withing the class itself and its now working. just have to get hold of the authorization part, when the access tokens are not present

Comment: ok. that can be done. but what if the configuration file does not exist, say for the first time the application is launched. i wish to display another window for the authorization in that case

Comment: that way you would create another class (`ErrorWindow`) and initialize it instead of your `MainWindow` in case the file doesn't exist.